# Collect KeyErrors from Ruby hash into array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-hash

I need to extract multiple fields from hash. But I respect my client and I want to gather all missed fields instead of returning it one by one. My idea was to use `#fetch`, intercept error with `KeyError`, put `error.key` into instance variable array and return proper error explanation with full list of missed keys.
Something like that

```rb
class Extractor

  def initialize hash
    @hash = hash
    @missed_keys = []
  end

  def call
    extract_values
    return "Missed keys: #{@missed_keys.join(', ')}" if @missed_keys.present?
  rescue KeyError => e
    puts 'Field was missed'
    @missed_keys << e.key
    return 'Error'
  end

  private

  def extract_values
    {
      value_1: @hash.fetch(:required_field_1),
      value_2: @hash.fetch(:required_field_2),
      value_3: @hash.fetch(:required_field_3)
    }
  end
end
```

When I try to process hash without required fields I got 'Error' after the first missed field:

```
pry(main)> Extractor.new(hash: {}).call
Field was missed
=> "Error"
```

Any clues?

DrySchema and other hash validators are not an option.

Comment: What output are you trying to produce?

Comment: And where do value1, value2, required_field1, required_field2 come from? Is it hard code?

Comment: See the answer below please. Basically this particular class is just a mapper. But this is a highly simplified version of a real problem

Comment: SO doesn't work this way. Please update your question. And I don't understand how your extractor from your answer will work if there is no missed keys. It will return `nil` in this case. Is it what you want?

Comment: My question was not about how that class supposed to work, but how can that class handle the error properly? I provided the detailed answer. This is exactly how SO works. 

Anyway, once you are interested:
If ```call``` method doesn't cause any error (```missed_keys``` are not presented) execution returns a result of ```extract_values``` .  For example if we have valid input hash ```Extractor.new({required_field_1: 'a', required_field_2: 'b', required_field_3: 'c'}).call``` output would be ```{value_1: 'a', value_2: 'b', value_3: 'c'}```. As I said - just simple mapper

Comment: No, this code will return `nil`, not hash :) And BTW there will not any output in this case. Did you try to run it? And please note that SO doesn't work this way, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yeah, you are right, nil. Whatever you say, man

Answer (score 1):

An issue with the provided solution is that the extracted values are never returned in the happy path (which presumably is important?). The `call` method is also stateful / non-idempotent. Subsequent calls to `call` will duplicate the `missing-keys`.

Finally - not sure how it's being used, but I don't love a method that returns either a hash or a string.

An alternative that attempts to follow a more functional pattern might look like:

```rb
class Extractor
  attr_reader :hash, :missed_keys, :required_keys

  def initialize hash
    @hash = hash
    @missed_keys = []
    @required_keys = [:required_field_1, :required_field_2, :required_field_3]
  end

  def call
    validate_keys_exist!
    extract_values
  end

  private

  def validate_keys_exist!
    missed_keys = find_missing_keys
    raise MissingKeysError, "Missed keys: #{missed_keys.join(', ')}" if missed_keys.any?
  end

  def find_missing_keys
    required_keys - hash.keys
  end

  def extract_values
    hash.slice(*required_keys) 
    # not sure if you need to map the keys to new values.
    # if so you can iterate over a hash of `from: :to` pairs instead of the
    # required_keys array.
  end
  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. The reason is in intercept level and method closures.
In aforementioned implementation Ruby tried to execute `call` method, got an error and exits.

If we rework it like that:

```rb
class Extractor

  def initialize hash
    @hash = hash
    @missed_keys = []
  end

  def call
    extract_values
    return "Missed keys: #{@missed_keys.join(', ')}" if @missed_keys.present?
  end

  private

  def extract_values
    {
      value_1: @hash.fetch(:required_field_1),
      value_2: @hash.fetch(:required_field_2),
      value_3: @hash.fetch(:required_field_3)
    }
  rescue KeyError => e
    puts 'Field was missed'
    @missed_keys << e.key
    nil
  end
  
end
```

it looks better, but still not what we wanted:

```
pry(main)> Extractor.new(hash: {}).call
Field was missed
=> "Missed keys: required_field_1"
```

This is because ruby tried to execute `extract_values` method, encounters first missed value and exits

So the solution as follow:

```rb
class Extractor

  def initialize hash
    @hash = hash
    @missed_keys = []
  end

  def call
    extract_values
    return "Missed keys: #{@missed_keys.join(', ')}" if @missed_keys.present?
  end

  private

  def extract_values
    {
      value_1: fetch_value(:required_field_1),
      value_2: fetch_value(:required_field_2),
      value_3: fetch_value(:required_field_3)
    }
  end

  def fetch_value(key)
    @hash.fetch(key)
  rescue KeyError => e
    puts 'Field was missed'
    @missed_keys << e.key
    nil
  end
  
end
```

```
Extractor.new(hash: {}).call
Field was missed
Field was missed
Field was missed
=> "Missed keys: required_field_1, required_field_2, required_field_3"
```

Error interception is accomplished on the `fetch_value` level and Ruby skips required values one by one